# Mapbox issue with parsing json data for heatmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mapbox

My code is this

```
heat = L.heatLayer([], { maxZoom: 12 }).addTo(map);
 $.getJSON("js/example-single.geojson", function(data) {
    var geojsosn = L.geoJson(data, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          console.log(feature.geometry.coordinates[0] ,feature.geometry.coordinates[1]);
        heat.addLatLng(feature.geometry.coordinates[0], feature.geometry.coordinates[1]);

      }
    });
```

but am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined"

please tell how to fix this, if my code is wrong somebody show me how to parse json data for heat map in mapbox

my json data is

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [13.353323936462402, 38.11200434622822]},
      "properties": {"marker-color": "#000"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addLatLng` probably expects `L.latLng` objects or something that has lat & lng properties.

```
var heat = L.heatLayer([], { maxZoom: 12 }).addTo(map);
$.getJSON('js/example-single.geojson', function(data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            feature.geometry.coordinates.forEach(function(p) {
                heat.addLatLng(L.latLng(p[0], p[1]));
            });
        }
    });
});
```